# AngularJS reference other pages

Tags: html, angularjs, razor

I'm trying to create code that dynamically outputs multiple links to other HTML pages depending on which option was selected and when a link is clicked it takes you to that page. I managed to get the page links to appear on the page the way I want, but when the link is clicked I get a 404 error. I'm using Razors `@Url.Action` code to call an angularjs `{{ expression }}` which may be the problem but I'm not sure. If the code I have now can be tweaked to work that would be great, but if you have a different angular directive to get the job done that would be good too.

**HTML**

```
// Repeats all the available options until there are none left
<div style="text-align:center" ng-repeat="page in pages">
    // Grabs the page name from the angular controller
    <a ng-href="@Url.Action("{{ page.name }}", "Dashboards")">{{ page.name }}</a>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
app.controller('FormController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

          var groupOne = [            
            { name: 'BudgetComparison' }
          ];

          var groupTwo = [
            { name: 'Optimize' },
            { name: 'Construction Program' },
            { name: 'BudgetCharts' }               
          ];

          var groupThree = [               
            { name: 'Import' }  
          ];

          var groupFour = [
            { name: 'EDITBudgetAmounts' },
            { name: 'ReviewAndAdjust' },
            { name: 'Export' },
            { name: 'ExportStrategies' }
          ];

          $scope.$watch("displayOption", function (displayOption) {
              if (displayOption) {
                  var value1 = displayOption.fiftyMill;
                  var value2 = displayOption.hundredMill;
                  var value3 = displayOption.statusQuo;
                  var value4 = displayOption.doNothing;

                  $scope.pages = null;
                  $scope.message = null;

                    if (value1 === true && value2 === true && value3 === true) {
                        $scope.pages = groupOne.concat(groupTwo);
                    }else if ((value1 === true || value2 === true) && value3 === true) {
                        $scope.pages = groupTwo;
                    }else if (value1 === true && value2 === true) {
                        $scope.pages = groupOne;
                    } else if (value1 === true || value2 === true || value3 === true) {
                        $scope.pages = groupFour;
                    } else if(value4 === true) {
                        $scope.message = 'No Options';
                    } else {
                        $scope.pages = groupThree;
                    }
              }
          }, true);
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC encodes the url generated from `Url.Action`, you need to decode it. You can use `@Html.Raw()` or something like this:

```
@{
  var url = Url.Action("{{ page.name }}", "Dashboards");
  url = url = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
}
```

...

```
<a ng-href="@url">{{ page.name }}</a>
```

Comment: So where would i place both of those code snippets? in the place of my anchor tag?